# How to change a foreach method to work atomically using compute()

Tags: java, foreach, atomic

Anyone knows how can I change this operation below to be atomic? This count variable is a hashmap<String, Integer> and I need to use the compute method (existing on map objects) to make this code thread safe. The first code snippet below is the old code that works fine, but it is not thread safe.

```
PageParser.Result result = parserFactory.get(url).parse();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : result.getWordCounts().entrySet()) {
    if (counts.containsKey(e.getKey())) {
        counts.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + counts.get(e.getKey()));
    } else {
        counts.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

The code below is what I did trying to use the compute (atomic) method, but it didn't work.

```
PageParser.Result result = parserFactory.get(url).parse();
for (ConcurrentMap.Entry<String, Integer> e : result.getWordCounts().entrySet()) {
    counts.compute(e.getKey(), (k, v) -> {
        if (counts.containsKey(k)) {
            return counts.put(k, v + counts.get(k));
        } else {
            return counts.put(k, v);
        }
    });
}
```

Don't notice ConcurrentMap instead of Map, I changed it in the second part, but the error is not about it.
I need to change the code that is commented to use the compute, but I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: Why does this need to be thread-safe?

Comment: This code is supposed to be accessed by multiple threads

Comment: And making the method `synchronized` isn't good enough?

Comment: To be honest, I would like to use the synchronized, but the teacher says that we need to implement the Map#compute in this case, probably for performance stuff